# Reformatting a data frame to find frequencies

Tags: r

I currently have this data frame:

`sex Dose weekReceived
1   M    1            1
2   F    2            2
3   M    3            2
4   M    1            3
5   M    1            2
6   F    2            1
7   M    1            1`

and I would like this data frame:

`weekReceived Dose M F
1            1    1 2 0
2            1    2 0 1
3            2    1 1 0
4            2    2 0 1
5            2    3 1 0
6            3    1 1 0`

To explain the second data frame, what I am trying to do is calculate the number of males and females who have received each dose by week (e.g. for line 1 in the second data frame tells us that two males received dose 1 in week 1).

Which function do I use for this sort of reformat?

Answer (score 0):

We get the `count` of all the columns, and `spread` the 'sex' with the frequency column 'n' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    count(weekReceived, Dose, sex) %>%
    spread(sex, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  weekReceived  Dose     F     M
#         <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1            1     1     0     2
#2            1     2     1     0
#3            2     1     0     1
#4            2     2     1     0
#5            2     3     0     1
#6            3     1     0     1
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M"), Dose = c(1L, 
 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), weekReceived = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
 "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```